# Can't I use the HTTPS URL of a Facebook page in a Facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, https, facebook-like

I have to add a Facebook like button on a website. The like button points to a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Sp1nDJs).

The following works fine:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/Sp1nDJs" 
data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="true"></div>
```

But when I use the HTTPS URL of the Facebook page, i.e. `http://www.facebook.com/Sp1nDJs` instead of `https://www.facebook.com/Sp1nDJs`, the like count is 0: (only the `data-href` HTML5 Attribute has been changed in the following)

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Sp1nDJs" 
data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" 
data-share="true"></div>
```

Why?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: Since this question received no answer, I posted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Cant-I-use-the-HTTPS-URL-of-a-Facebook-page-in-a-Facebook-like-button